# Getting multiple variable types in columns to be separated into their own columns when cleaning data

Tags: r, rstudio, data-cleaning

The columns have multiple variables, such as the year, the IEA grouping, and the onshore and offshore status. how can i get all of these variables to be their own column and make the data set taller?

Im fairly new R and am somewhat familiar with melting and casting a messy data set but idk how to approach this kind of problem.

basically i would like to have a column for each of the current column variables, which would necessitate way more rows but would make the data much easier to work with.[this is the top right corner of the data set. as you can see, each of the columns currently have 6 different variables, and i would like each to have their own column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dywah.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: https://o365coloradoedu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/joga5948_colorado_edu/Ed-4rIl4JDBNmOVsk6r0h9sBYMrnKWoNwEZvD2F6xo6u8Q?e=Z7RTHR